# GIS used to analyse micro-environment

Tags: analysis, environmental-monitoring

Can anybody give me some articles or show me some link where GIS is used to analyse and manage micro-environment, such as a college campus or a small locality. I need to do a project on micro-environment analysis using GIS, so i need some references from where i can get some ideas. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are a few working examples from the University of Arkansas, namely [CAST](http://cast.uark.edu):

- Laser-scanning of university facilities and historic buildings: http://www.cast.uark.edu/home/research/visualizationanimation/uofavis.html
- Campus map: http://campusmaps.uark.edu/ - CAD data of building footprints brought into a Google Maps application
- RUSS - Room Use Survey System: https://fama.cast.uark.edu/ and http://www.cast.uark.edu/home/research/urban-infrastructure-projects/room-use-survey-system-russ.html - provides building, floor, and room level detail on how space is allocated in campus buildings
- 3D scan of historic campus building: http://www.cast.uark.edu/home/research/urban-infrastructure-projects.html

Many of these projects involve [terrestrial laser scanning](http://gmv.cast.uark.edu/scanning-2/mid-range-terrestrial-laser-scanning/).

Comment: Sweet examples Chad!

Answer (score 3):

[University of Texas A&M](http://library.tamu.edu/about/collections/map-gis-collections-services/gis-data-online-interactive-maps/gis-online-data.html) Uses gis to manage facilities.
Esri has extensive data models and education on this subject.
[Campus Editing](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=526c50646cea49fbbc714a4171f11ba6) is an online map. (arcgisonline)
Which has the [campus basemap](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=0d9299ec726a4ea7b9c6c1edb07a7483)
A [search](http://www.arcgis.com/home/search.html?q=Building%20Interior%20Space%20Data%20Model&t=content) on arcgislonline will reveal the data model and other information including a [free online training](http://training.esri.com/gateway/index.cfm?fa=catalog.courseDetail&CourseID=50128180_10.x).

Answer (score 2):

I think [ArcGIS Spatial Analyst Tutoria](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CDYQFjAA&url=http://webhelp.esri.com/ArcGISdesktop/9.3/pdf/Spatial_Analyst_Tutorial.pdf&ei=2ZtuUYetDMuk2gX5wIG4Dw&usg=AFQjCNGL0RQIh4VZxgBrO2EwaRz9aU_yZw&sig2=zVIh5_KFU96i1IEEQSV3lg&bvm=bv.45368065,d.b2I)l is the best tutorial for site selection and spatial analysis . It's about finding a site for new school . users learn how to manipulate and combine data for spatial analysis.weighted overlay method used for the site selection.Users also learn how to use model builder and create a tool to automate the project.

Answer (score 2):

A study was done at the Hospital in Sault Ste. Marie Canada for MRSA infection control: http://www.ssmic.com/UploadedFiles/files/GIS_Hospital_Infection_Control_CaseStudy_sept24_final_2008.pdf

They used GIS to monitor the spread of the disease and managed to determine the staff weren't following their own protocals, thus spreading the infection.

Answer (score 1):

I understand your question to be calling for environmental GIS-related projects at a small scale.  A few ideas come to mind:

1. Tracking changes in forest cover utilizing [classification of NAIP/Landsat
   imagery](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2011/05/28/classifying-landsat-image-services-to-make-a-land-cover-map/) or comparisons of [temporal NLCD datasets](http://www.mrlc.gov/finddata.php).
2. Identifying potential point source water pollution and modelling basin run-off
   properties utilizing [EPA geospatial data](https://edg.epa.gov/clipship/) and ArcGIS [hydrology toolset](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009z0000004w000000).  There are tutorials [here](http://www.trentu.ca/library/data/DelineateWatersheds_V10.pdf) and [here](http://www.lib.virginia.edu/scholarslab/resources/class/foresthydro/foresthydroexercise.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

We used it as a design space for a stream rehab project where the study area was about 1000 feet. We were able to use GIS to model many different design surfaces by driving a virtual backhoe and using those results as modeling inputs. The platform proved to be much more stable than our original approach.

[paper:](http://www.knoxcounty.org/stormwater/pdfs/BCatHCPrehab.pdf)

[presentation:](http://www.knoxcounty.org/stormwater/pdfs/srp2010_abd_11_9.pdf)